# How to filter at multiple levels on rails includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Considering the following code

```
@stages = FunnelStage.kept.order(:position)
.includes(:template_timings, kept_schedule_tasks: [:template_timings, kept_schedule_sub_tasks: :template_timings ])
.where(template_timings: {timeframe_template_id: 1}).uniq
```

I want to filter template_timings by where timeframe_template_id = 1. But only the FunnelStage timings are filtered e.g. stages.first.template_timings are ok.
But e.g. @stages.first.kept_schedule_tasks.first.template_timings still contains ALL template_timings...

```
@stages = FunnelStage.kept
                     .order(:position)
                     .includes(:template_timings, kept_schedule_tasks: [:template_timings, kept_schedule_sub_tasks: :template_timings])
                     .where(template_timings: { timeframe_template_id: 1 }, 
                            kept_schedule_tasks: { template_timings: { timeframe_template_id: 1 },
                                                  kept_schedule_sub_tasks: { template_timings: { timeframe_template_id: 1 }}})
                     .uniq
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

also:  `has_many :kept_schedule_tasks, -> { kept.where(show_in_scheduler: true).order(:position) }, class_name: "FunnelTask"`